# Pusher: Decrease timeout for connection state

Tags: java, websocket, timeout, pusher

I'm currently experimenting with websockets using the Pusher library for Java.

Pusher automatically changes its connection state from CONNECTED to DISCONNECTED if the internet connection is lost. However, this only seems to happen after 150 seconds of being disconnected. This is very unfortunate as in those 150s, a lot of messages can get lost, and a de facto old message can still be seen as the most up-to-date.

How can I know if the last received message is the most up-to-date? Or is there any way to decrease the timeout for the connection state?

Here is the pusher code I'm using:

```
import com.pusher.client.Pusher;
import com.pusher.client.channel.Channel;
import com.pusher.client.channel.ChannelEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.channel.SubscriptionEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionState;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionStateChange;


public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        // Create a new Pusher instance
        Pusher pusher = new Pusher("PusherKey");

        pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                System.out.println("State changed to " + change.getCurrentState() +
                                   " from " + change.getPreviousState());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                System.out.println("There was a problem connecting!");
            }
        }, ConnectionState.ALL);

        // Subscribe to a channel
         Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("channel", new ChannelEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channelName) {
                 System.out.println("Subscribed!");
             }

             @Override
             public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, String data) {
                 System.out.println("desilo se");
             }
         });

         // Bind to listen for events called "my-event" sent to "my-channel"
         channel.bind("my-event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onEvent(String channel, String event, String data) {
                 System.out.println("Received event with data: " + data);
             }
         });

        while(true){
            try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
            }

        }
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found the answer: Initiate Pusher-object with PusherOptions-object.

Here is the PusherOptions-class: http://pusher.github.io/pusher-java-client/src-html/com/pusher/client/PusherOptions.html

Here is a simple example how I decreased my connection-timeout from 150s to 15s:

```
// Define timeout parameters
PusherOptions opt = new PusherOptions();
opt.setActivityTimeout((long)10000L);
opt.setPongTimeout((long)5000L);

// Create a new Pusher instance
Pusher pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER_KEY, opt);
```

ActivityTimeout defines how often a ping is sent out to check the connectivity, PongTimeout defines the waiting time until a response from the ping-signal is expected.

The minimum ActivityTimeout is 1000ms, however such a low value is strongly discouraged by Pusher, probably to decrease the server-traffic.